# Saving an integer variable in Swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save an integer variable in swift/xcode so that when the user opens the application, the number they are incrementing stays the sames (is saved). So far, no luck with this code. The number always goes back to zero when I relaunch the app. The button below simply increments the smoke variable by 1, I want to save that data.

Thank you for your time.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var smoke = 0

@IBAction func incrementSmoke(_ sender: UIButton) {
    smoke+=1

    defaults.set(smoke, forKey: "smoke")

    numDaysLabel.text = String(defaults.integer(forKey: "smoke"))        
}
```

Comment: You aren't retrieving the previous session's value of "smoke" from UserDefaults at any point in the code you've shown.

Comment: What do you mean by the previous "session"?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, basically I want the label to stay the same after each session, how do I do this?

Comment: From the previous time you ran the app. You save the value to UserDefaults, but then you have to assign the saved value to the variable when you restart the app if you want to use it. Probably just need to put `smoke = defaults.integer(forKey: "smoke")` in the init method.

Comment: So do I have to save something to the "smoke" variable for next time? Ok thanks

Comment: You can't save anything to a variable long-term, they only exist temporarily and reset to whatever the initial value is (in your code, 0) every time. For long-term storage you have to use some sort of external method like UserDefaults, but then you also have to take the stored value from there and assign it to the variable every time you initialize it.

Comment: smoke = defaults.integer(forKey: "smoke") . Putting that in viewdidload worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an appropriate spot you should be initializing your `smoke` property with the value stored in `UserDefaults`. For example, you might want to do this in `viewDidLoad`, or you could just do it directly in the initializer where you declare the property.

```
var smoke = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "smoke")

@IBAction func incrementSmoke(_ sender: UIButton) {
    smoke += 1    
    UserDefaults.standard.set(smoke, forKey: "smoke")    
    numDaysLabel.text = String(smoke)
}
```

Note [`integer(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1407405-integer) will return `0` by default if there is no value stored in your `UserDefaults` already for that key. If you want to set an initial value for the key, [`register(defaults:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1417065-register).

Note, since your value is supposed to be an integer, you might as well use `integer(forKey:)` instead of `object(forKey:)` so you don't have to deal with an optional / `Any`.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

Set Value

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("Value", forKey: "Key") //setString
```

Get

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Key") //getString
```

Remove

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Key")
```

In your `viewDidLoad`

```
smoke = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "smoke") ?? 0
```

Then

```
numDaysLabel.text = "\(smoke)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one line of code to get data from `UserDefaults`. If there is data then it is returned, or it returns 0.

```
let smoke = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "smoke") ?? 0
```